# Update Host field name with the seed url

Tags: elasticsearch, web-crawler, stormcrawler

I am working on Storm Crawler 1.10 and ES 6.4.2. I inserted couple of urls in the seeds file and I am looking to filter the results based on the host name. Is there any way that I can tell the crawler store the seed url in host field.

For Eg., my seeds urls are **https://abce.com/ghi, https://abce.com/jkl, https://abce.com/mno**. Need to filter the results based on https://abce.com/ghi. Tried with elastic search wildcard filters but the results are not accuarate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The host field is used for sharding and is created automatically. Just create a new searchable field for it.

You can add a custom metadata in the seed file for each entry e.g.
 *https://abce.com/ghi seed=ghi*

You'll need to specify the key for the metadata transfer so that the outlinks get it:

```
 metadata.transfer:
   - seed
```

then configure the indexer so that it creates a field for it

```
 indexer.md.mapping:
  - seed=seed
```

Finally, you might want to refine the ES schema and make that field a *keyword*

```
"seed": {
         "type": "keyword",
         "index": "true",
         "store": true
        }
```

Comment: **Updated** :   I added **metadata.transfer** and **indexer.md.mapping** in **crawl-conf.yaml** and in I modified the seed file as `seed=https://abce.com/ghi
 seed=https://abce.com/jkl 
 seed=https://abce.com/mno ` urls are not crawled only the seed urls are injected in the format `"url" : "seed=https://www.acde/ghi"`.I tried one more way `https://abce.com/ghi seed=ghi 
 https://abce.com/jkl seed=jkl
 https://abce.com/mno seed=mno` This gives me fetch error because the url is not proper format.

Comment: utl \t key=value, not space